# How query get value where date Now in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    TGL = CONVERT(DATE, TIMESTAMP), RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(hour, TimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS jam,
    Nilai = MAX(NILAI)
FROM 
    PLC_CPress2P1 
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, TIMESTAMP), RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(hour, TimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, TIMESTAMP), RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(hour, TimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) DESC
```

I've tried `GATEDATE()` and `NOW` - both do not work

Comment: It's `getdate()` NOT `gatedate()`

Comment: Or better yet (since SQL Server 2008) - use `SYSDATETIME()`  or `SYSUTCDATETIME()`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to select everthing from a table where the date equals today?

In that case, you can just do it like this:

```
SELECT *columns*
FROM *table_name*
WHERE *specified_date_column* = CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

Here you can see all SQL Date functions: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp